# Legacy opengl - Why is phong shading not possible?

Tags: opengl

I know that legacy opengl only supports flat and gouraud shading but I was wondering why phong shading is not possible?

Someone said that it is not possible because legacy opengl discards the normals, but I have no idea where they are discarded nor why they are discarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even legacy openGL doesn't discard normals. The difference when it it comes to shading is, that to save time in shading legacy opgenGL only calculates shading values at every vertex position, blending color for every triangle between the 3 color calculated for the vertexes.

This method is also called **Gouraud shading**.

**Phong shading** on the other hand will calculate lighting values for every pixel rendered on the screen - not just for the vertexes and somehow "guess" all the other lighting values.

### Guessing why ...

Most probably **Gouraud shading** was chosen as it involves a lot less computation it achieves a relatively realistic looking approximation.

**Phong shading** may achieve an even more realistic looking approximation but the difference in computation can be very big.

### Example

A single quad displayed on the screen will just need 4 more or less complex computations for the vertexes, while blending between those will be much cheaper in terms of calculation time.

Phong shading on the other hand will perform lighting calculations for every pixel that makes up your quad shape, which can get a lot of calculations pretty fast. Imagine your quad gets rasterzed to an area of (100 x 100) pixels for example.

Depending int the order shapes get drawn the number of per-pixel calculations that has to be performed can be drastically larger than the resolution of the screen if a lot of obscured objects get drawn first as they will all pass the **depth-test** just to be overdrawn later on.

### What's missing ?

What's missing in legacy opengl to perform fast **Phong shading** are not any missing or otherwise discarded normals but a way to perform the mentioned per-pixel operations pretty fast. This is possible with so called **Shaders**. Small programs running on the graphics hardware itself.

Legacy opengl doesn't allow for customization of the rendering process at such a fine grained level as the whole rendering process can only be tewaked at few pre-defined places in the so called **fixed function pipeline**.

### Summary

Other than you were told the main problem in trying to perform **Phong Shading** using legacy opengl is not that any normals are discarded, but that it wasn't designed to perform **per-pixel** lighting but only **per-vertex** lighting.

Comment: Okay so theoretically it could be done, even in legacy opengl? But they just decided to not implement it?

Comment: Great, you're confusing different terms. -1

Comment: @SigTerm As I don't see where - tell me where the confusion started and I'll fix it.

Comment: @mikyra: Wait till I write my answer.

Comment: I take it back. There's phong shading and phong illumination model. NO answer from me then.