# Inter dependency between gl_color and material

Tags: opengl, glsl, light

1. In the fixed pipeline, what happens of the color set by gl_color when using a material?
2. Is there a way to retrieve the color set by gl_color in a glsl fragment shader?

Comment: And do you know which shader model (Gouraud, Phong...) is used by the old fixed pipeline, when only a color is set?

Comment: when enabled `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` then material is modulated by the `glColor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 2.1 API Specification - 2.15.3 Shader Variables, page 76](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec21.pdf)

> Vertex Attributes
>
> Vertex shaders can access built-in vertex attribute variables corresponding to the per-vertex state set by commands such as **Vertex**, **Normal**, **Color**. .....

See [OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification - 7.3 Vertex Shader Built-In Attributes, page 49](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf):

> The following attribute names are built into the OpenGL vertex language and can be used from within a vertex shader to access the current values of attributes declared by OpenGL.
>
> ```
> attribute vec4 gl_Color;
> ```

This means, the color which is set by `glColor*` can be accessed by the attribute `attribute vec4 gl_Color;` in the **vertex shader**.

See [OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification - 7.5 Built-In Uniform State, page 50]:

> As an aid to accessing OpenGL processing state, the following uniform variables are built into the OpenGL Shading Language.
>
> .....
>
> ```
> struct gl_MaterialParameters {
>     vec4 emission; // Ecm
>     vec4 ambient; // Acm
>     vec4 diffuse; // Dcm
>     vec4 specular; // Scm
>     float shininess; // Srm
> };
> uniform gl_MaterialParameters gl_FrontMaterial;
> uniform gl_MaterialParameters gl_BackMaterial;
> ```

This means, that the material properties which are set by `glMaterial`, can be accessed by the built-in uniform variables `gl_FrontMaterial`, `gl_BackMaterial`.

See also [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) Quick Reference Guide](http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf)

---

Referring to the additional question in the comment:

> And do you know which shader model (Gouraud, Phong...) is used by the old fixed pipeline, when only a color is set?

Phong shading is not possibel in the OpenGL fixed function pipeline. See [Legacy opengl - Why is phong shading not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911806/legacy-opengl-why-is-phong-shading-not-possible)

Except you implement phong shading in your own shader. See [Per Fragment Lighting](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php)

In general the shading model can be set by [`glShadeModel`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml), which can be either `GL_SMOOTH` or `GL_FLAT`.

---

Further note:

If Lighting is enabled (`glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`), then then you have to set the color (`gl_Color`) by [`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml).

But if additionally `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` is enabled (`glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)`), then you can specify that the material parameters track the current color, by [`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml).

e.g.

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
```

See [How lighting works](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/How_lighting_works)